# show non duplicated rows in a join and where stipulations mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to show all the rows and only one of the duplicated row, but the query has a join and where stipulations.

```
select 
     judges.judgesid, 
     judges.id, 
     judges.eventid, 
     judges.category
from judges 
left join event as eventdt 
  on judges.eventid = eventdt.eventid 
where judges.eventid = '125432' and judges.e_date = eventdt.e_date
```

table similar to:

```
e_date  | category    
1/1/2001| start    
1/1/2001| intermediate    
1/1/2001| advanced    
1/1/2001| advanced
```

I want to show

```
e_date  | category
1/1/2001| start
1/1/2001| intermediate
1/1/2001| advanced
```

I tried distinct but I guess i did it wrong because i would get an error or the all the rows would show.

Comment: use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute the DISTINCT keyword for a GROUP BY clause.

```
 select 
         judges.judgesid, 
         judges.id, 
         judges.eventid, 
         judges.category
    from judges 
    left join event as eventdt 
      on judges.eventid = eventdt.eventid 
    where judges.eventid = '125432' and judges.e_date = eventdt.e_date
       GROUP BY 
  judges.eventid, 
     judges.category;
```

Comment: @user3389848  If this has solved the problem. accept it by ticking it and marking it as solved, so that it can help those who may confront the same problem.